# venv is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

I receive the following error when creating a virtualenv and am unsure how to overcome it. My OS is Oracle Linux Server 7.9.

> No module named venv__main__; 'venv' is a package and cannot be directly executed

I have tried the following commands:

> /opt/oss/python394/bin/python3 -m venv env

> python3 -m venv env